# No item exists at it may have been deleted after clicking save button

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, error, item, item-level-permissions

I have a weird one here. I have a infopath form with a button at the bottom performing a save action.

Users are able to open the form in edit mode and click the save button. Once the user clicks the button they get hit with a No item exists at it may have been deleted message. Even though the user gets that message changes were made to the form as expected.

Any clue why users are experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have a list augmented by InfoPath: In your browser, go to List settings > Advanced Settings. Check the Item-level Permissions. try using Read access: Read all items and then Create and Edit access: Create and edit all items.

The list may currently show Create items and edit items that were created by the user. If that isn't true or still causes issues, try advancing a single approver to Design level permissions for the list and have them try. The above item-level permissions applies to users with Contribute and/or Edit permissions.

I hope that helps.